# Missing SQL view in geoserver

Tags: geoserver, sql-view

At the moment I'm trying to make an SQL view in geoserver, however I do not have the option to make an SQL view. see picture below.
Anyone else who has had problems with this issue? I can't find any documentation how to fix this problem so help will be appreciated!

[image: This is the "Add new Layer" screen]

Comment: What is your data source? Does it support views?

Comment: Thanks for responding, it was a shapefile source so that was the reason it is not possible.

For the people who come to this post with the same question, the datasource .SHP does not support SQLviews on geoserver. There are two possible solutions for this:

1) change your data source to a dbs like postgres.
2) Use CQL filter instead directly in your code!

Comment: you should self-answer (and accept it) with this

Comment: great, thanks for the info, sorry I'm kinda new to stack :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for responding, it was a shapefile source so that was the reason it is not possible. For the people who come to this post with the same question, the datasource .SHP does not support SQLviews on geoserver. There are two possible solutions for this: 1) change your data source to a dbs like postgres. 2) Use CQL filter instead directly in your code!